# Unix display info about files matching one of two patterns

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I'm trying to display on a Unix system recursively all the files that start with an `a` or ends with an `a` with some info about them: name, size and last modified.

I tried `find . -name "*a" -o -name "a*"` and it displays all the files okay but when I add `-printf "%p %s"` it displays only one result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the same action to apply to both patterns, you need to group them with parentheses. Also, you should add a newline to printf, otherwise all of the output will be on one line:

```
find . \( -name "*a" -o -name "a*" \) -printf "%p %s\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.hh" | xargs ls -l | awk '{print $9,$6,$7,$8,$5}'
```